# LAMP Staging Server with linux users

Tags: linux, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LAMP Staging Server with linux users](https://serverfault.com/questions/101096/lamp-staging-server-with-linux-users)

I need to have a mirror server of my production server so that I can test everything on that server first before implementing on production.

To mirror production server I need to copy current PHP code, uploaded files, database and linux machine users (as my PHP script need these accounts and home directories) from production server to new server and I also need to update all these from production server each time when I need to test anything on staging server because production server gets updated by the users.

I can update everything manually except Linux users and their home directories as they may affect the system. Is there any way to replicate a Linux machine users to another machine at the same time when they are created on production machine or is there any automated system they to staging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I need to test anything on staging server because production server gets updated by the users

You are doing this backwards.  Users should be updating the staging server, and then changes should tested and then pushed to production.

Use a configuration management tool like puppet to create define user accounts, then they can be applied to staging and production servers, and kept in sync.

Comment: No, I mean the site users. They will surely be updated the live/production server so when I need to test something on staging server should I copy these changes (like database/ uploaded media files/ databases) to staging server or it will automatically sync everything.
+
The production server administrator needs to create some users account in production machine frequently and all these users should be replicated automatically on staging server as well so that I can test my code on  staging server.